# iPhone UINavigationBar - Set width and margin of rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a background image for a button, with the dimensions of 80x30 pixels.

I use the code below to set the background in my view-controller, and the result is this:

[image: Top and corners are noisy]

As you can see, the corners and the top of the right button is messed up.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIImage *favoriteBtnImgNormal = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite-btn-normal"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 30, 0)];
    UIImage *favoriteBtnImgTouch = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite-btn-touch"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 30, 0)];

    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:favoriteBtnImgNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:favoriteBtnImgTouch forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:favoriteBtnImgTouch forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-10.0, 0.0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Note that I do this in a single view-controller, I use the appearance API to set general styles. But here I want to override the general appearance.

If I just get the images without the resizable-stuff, it looks like this:

[image: Too large]

Now the edges and corners are fine, but the button is too large.

I'm sure I'm doing this all wrong, so I need someone to point out what I could do to scale buttons correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

button.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );

[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(YourAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.contentEdgeInsets = (UIEdgeInsets){.right=-10};

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Answers should be more than just a code dump or a link to another site. Answers should be able to stand on their own and include enough context so that they make sense.

Comment: I realize my question was not answered, though I've found a way to achieve what I wanted by using the Appearance API, and using re-sizable images which is the preferred way to go about this.